# Programmatically find application modules

Tags: android, module

I have an app that manage some services. These services developed as separate module-applications and can be of two types - sensors and callbacks. When main application starts I want to know is there some modules installed on device? If yes, which apps are modules and what type they have? So the question is how can I find all module-applications installed on device and determine which type they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define appropriate intent-filters for your services which e.g. react on particular actions for sensor or callback.

In the controlling activity you can then create an `intent` for the desired action, and call `getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(intent, flags)` to get matching services.